# Migrations is not detecting added property to ApplicationRole : IdentityRole

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-3

I am trying to add a property to the AspNetRoles table in ASP.NET Core Identity. I assumed the process would be the following:

1. Create an ApplicationRole class that implements IdentityRole just like ApplicationUser implements IdentityUser.
2. Add new property to ApplicationRole class.
3. Replace IdentityRole with ApplicationRole throughout the application where necessary.

i.e.

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

4. Add-Migration

During step 4 when adding the migration I end up with an empty migration file. Any idea why this isn't working like it works when adding additional properties to ApplicationUser and then adding migration?

I noticed ApplicationDbContext implements IdentityDbContext. How can I add my ApplicationRole to this. I believe this is my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how is your ApplicationDbContext, but I think you have to put something like this in the declaration of it:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string>
```

Comment: I assume if I just want to use the default GUID functionality I pass string in?

Comment: Yes, the default id is string.